# How to change the background color of ElevatedButton in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-widget

I tried to change the background color of ElevatedButton but it gave me an error. How can I change it?

```
ElevatedButton(
  onPressed: null,
  style: ButtonStyle(backgroundColor: Colors.red), // Error
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try This way

```
   ElevatedButton(            
            onPressed: () {},
            style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                primary: Colors.red,
                ),)
```